# If statement with OR condition in java

Tags: java, if-statement

I am writing the code as`if(!"Admin".equals(role) || !"IAP_PMO".equals(role))
return new ModelAndView("error")` It is not checking the both conditions but if I write only one like `if(!"Admin".equals(role))` then its working.What is the error?

Comment: One of both conditions will always be true.

Comment: `||` only checks its second argument  if the first was false. Are you sure you don't need `&&`?

Comment: Actually Admin and PMO both are same role.If Admin or  PMO role is not there then it should return error .That's what I am trying to do.That means some contains Admin as a role some contains PMO as a role.I want to check any of them

Comment: "If Admin or PMO role is not there then" --> you (should) mean to say "If Admin **and** PMO role is not there then". And in your Java code, you should replace `||` with `&&`.

Comment: No any of them is not true then do next.I want to do that

Comment: For some reason you didn't say what the expected behavior was or how the observed behavior differed from it. Consider that if `role.equals("IAP_PMO")` is true, then `return new ModelAndView("error");` will execute. If `role.equals("Admin")` is true, same action: error. If neither is true, same action: error. Draw the truth tables and see for yourself. (It's always good to see for yourself.) Always enclose `if` and loop bodies in curly braces.